# Scala pattern match against a Java enum type

Tags: scala, enums

I have a Java enum type that has some Strings and I want to pattern match against in. Here is what I have done so far:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  YEAR, MONTH;
}
```

In my scala function, I do the following:

```
timePeriod.toUpperCase match {
  case MyEnum.YEAR.name => doSomething
  case MyEnum.MONTH.name => doSomething
}
```

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
stable identifier required, but YEAR.name found
```

It is not informative enough for me to understand the root cause of the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have method calls as clauses in a match, because the result of the method may differ. We know in this case it doesn't but there's no way to indicate to the compiler that a method call is constant.

You could do this:

```
  timePeriod.toUpperCase match {
    case period if period == MyEnum.YEAR.name =>
    case period if period == MyEnum.MONTH.name =>
  }
```

Which is a bit more verbose. Someone else may have a shorter and better suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `valueOf` method of a Java `Enum` to do the lookup:

```
MyEnum.valueOf(timePeriod.toUpperCase) match {
  case MyEnum.YEAR => doSomething
  case MyEnum.MONTH => doSomething
}
```

The resolution at `MyEnum.valueOf` method is strict and will throw an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` if the value being resolved is not part of the enum.

If you expect values not resolved by the Enum, you may want to contain the exception and add a default match to handle it. An idiomatic way to do that would be:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
Try{MyEnum.valueOf(timePeriod.toUpperCase)} match {
  case Success(MyEnum.YEAR) => doSomething
  case Success(MyEnum.MONTH) => doSomething
  case Failure(_) => handleDefault
}
```